# Как добавить категориальный столбец по какому-то условию с помощью метода assing() и pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я хочу добавить столбец `company` с помощью метода `assing`, где будет условие `sales >= 45000`, то добавить название компании

Вот датафрейм:

```
       name     region  sales   expenses
0      William  East    50000   42000
1      Emma     North   52000   43000
2      Sofia    East    90000   50000
3      Markus   South   34000   44000
4      Edward   West    42000   38000
5      Thomas   West    72000   39000
6      Ethan    South   49000   42000
7      Olivia   West    55000   60000
8      Arun     West    67000   39000
9      Anika    East    65000   44000
10     Paulo    South   67000   45000
```

Вот мой код:

```
df.assing(
    company = df.sales.apply(lambda x: x > 45000)
)
```

```
    name    region  sales   expenses company
0   William East    50000   42000   True
1   Emma    North   52000   43000   True
2   Sofia   East    90000   50000   True
3   Markus  South   34000   44000   False
4   Edward  West    42000   38000   False
5   Thomas  West    72000   39000   True
6   Ethan   South   49000   42000   True
7   Olivia  West    55000   60000   True
8   Arun    West    67000   39000   True
9   Anika   East    65000   44000   True
10  Paulo   South   67000   45000   True
```

Я хочу, чтобы вместо `True` было `PatnaCompany`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [105]: df.assign(company=np.where(df["sales"] >= 45000, "PatnaCompany", ""))
Out[105]:
       name region  sales  expenses       company
0   William   East  50000     42000  PatnaCompany
1      Emma  North  52000     43000  PatnaCompany
2     Sofia   East  90000     50000  PatnaCompany
3    Markus  South  34000     44000
4    Edward   West  42000     38000
5    Thomas   West  72000     39000  PatnaCompany
6     Ethan  South  49000     42000  PatnaCompany
7    Olivia   West  55000     60000  PatnaCompany
8      Arun   West  67000     39000  PatnaCompany
9     Anika   East  65000     44000  PatnaCompany
10    Paulo  South  67000     45000  PatnaCompany
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

или слегка дополните свой код, примерно так:

```
df.assign(company = df.sales.apply(lambda x: 'PatnaCompany' if x > 45000 else ''))
```